# Display members of a SC-group with filtered results

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to make a script on how to make a simple `get-ADGroupMember` but with several displayed results. One which the above cmdlet can display, and that is the 'mail'-attribute.

```
Get-ADGroupMember -identity "group-name one" -Recursive | Get-ADUser -property DisplayName | Select Name,DisplayName,mail
```

One simple solution would be to use the code below, as its displays the results I want all together (I have removed sensitive info in the output). As I'm going to present this information to a customer, I want a more "clean" look on the output, one which the above code could supply (user friendly). The first output works fine if not for the fact that it doesn't show the mail attribute.

```
Get-ADGroupMember -identity "avd-Barn- och utbildningskontoret" -Recursive | Get-ADUser -property mail

DistinguishedName : 
Enabled           : True
GivenName         : Lisa
mail              : 
Name              : 
ObjectClass       : user
ObjectGUID        : 98cb2a62
SamAccountName    : 
SID               : S-1-5-21
Surname           : surname
UserPrincipalName :
```

Is there a way to this?

Comment: Are you wanting at table format or a list format?

Comment: the property that contains the email address is `EmailAddress` not mail

Comment: mjolinor: it actually doesnt matter, as user friendly as possible.

Comment: Paul: the above string with code with property 'mail' actually works for me, i know the actually attributes name is "emailAdress" though.

Comment: See if this helps: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Select-FromGridView-521a56d8  You can output to a gridview, and specify the column headings you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this would be :

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "group-name one" -Recursive | Get-ADUser -properties DisplayName,mail | Select Name,DisplayName,mail
```

Comment: how would you go about adding several groups here?

Answer (score 1):

This gave me what I wanted. This way, I can add several groups at once as well if needed in the future.

```
$arrResults = @()
foreach($varGroup in (Get-ADGroupMember -identity "groupname")){
foreach($varUser in (Get-ADUser $varGroup -properties mail | select SamAccountName, mail)){
foreach($varUsor in (Get-ADUser $varGroup -properties DisplayName | select DisplayName)){
$objResult = New-Object PSobject
$objResult | Add-Member -membertype NoteProperty -Name "SamAccountName" -Value $varUser.SamAccountName
$objResult | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Mail" -Value $varUser.mail
$objResult | Add-Member -Membertype NoteProperty -Name "DisplayName" -Value $varUsor.DisplayName
$arrResults += $objResult
}
}
}
$arrResults
```